# Need help with my face recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I need help with my face recognition program. 
I got these errors when I build my program:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector(class std::vector<float,class std::allocator<float> > const &)" (?setSVMDetector@HOGDescriptor@cv@@UAEXABV?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl ppledetect(void)" (?ppledetect@@YAHXZ)    

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::HOGDescriptor::write(class cv::FileStorage &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (?write@HOGDescriptor@cv@@UBEXAAVFileStorage@2@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals
```

I got 11 these kinds of errors. 
3 of error LNK2019 while 8 of error LNK2001 and 1 of error LNK1120. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: I was tempted to make a little joke when I read the title of the question.

Answer (score 3):

HOGDescriptor is in opencv_objdetect.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means you are missing linker dependencies (lib files)

A search shows these files you will need to add in debug:

```
opencv_core220d.lib
opencv_highgui220d.lib
opencv_video220d.lib
opencv_ml220d.lib
opencv_legacy220d.lib
opencv_imgproc220d.lib
```

If you're using Visual Studio, you can go to :

*project properties* -> *Configuration properties* -> *Linker* -> *General*

From there, set the "Additional Library Directories".  This is where you enter the root directory where the lib files are located. eg: `C:\program files\opencv22\lib\`

You then need to go to *project properties* -> *Configuration properties* -> *Linker* -> *Input*

Under Additional Dependencies, you need to add those lib files there.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your help. I've tried your method but i still get the same error.

Comment: That likely due to a typo I just noticed.  Follow the updated instructions, and that should help you.

Answer (score 0):

The errors mean that OpenCV is not linked correctly. Make sure you follow the instructions at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and I resolved by previous answers.

If you're using Visual Studio: go to Project properties -> Configuration properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies and edit it.
You need to add "opencv_objdetect249d.lib" (I am using opencv 2.4.9 but your file name can be different, 249 can change. Look your ..\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib directory and write your file's name: opencv_objdetect???d.lib)